# I have some questions about how database version works on apps with sqflite?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am working on flutter nearly 6 months. I developed a flutter app with database SQFlite. Now clients use this app.
I have some questions about how database version works on apps with sqflite?
I have made a DatabaseHelper class it will create a db in the device of the user when the app is installed in the device.

Case: I added more columns in the tables, the db or tables doesn't update in the devices of users while update the the app.
(I add more 2 columns as firstname, lastname  in the edlTable)

How can I replace the oldone by updated db or the tables while updating the app? (without uninstall and install the app)

```
               class DatabaseHelper {
                static DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper; 
                  static Database _database;
     
             DatabaseHelper._createInstance();

              factory DatabaseHelper() {
                if (_databaseHelper == null) {
                _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._createInstance();
             }
              return _databaseHelper;
             }

         

                  Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {
                  Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                  String path = directory.path + 'edl.db';
                  var database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
                  return database;
                }


            String colEdlTable = 'table_edl';
            String colIdEdl = "idEdl";
            String colHeureDebut = "heureDebut";
            String colHeureFin = "heureFin";
            String colCommentaire = "commentaire";
            String colServerEdlId = 'serverEdlId';




               void _createDb(Database db, int newVersion) async {
                 await db.execute(
                    'CREATE TABLE $colEdlTable($colIdEdl INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
                    AUTOINCREMENT,$colHeureDebut TEXT, $colHeureFin TEXT, $colCommentaire TEXT, 
                  $colServerEdlId INTEGER)');}

                         }
```